# Create claims identity in Identity 3

Tags: razor, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

Visual Studio 2015 scaffolding uses `UserManager<TUser>` which cannot be used to create `ClaimsIdentity`. Does anyone have a working example on how to do this?

The VS2015 scaffolding throws errors:

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
    // Note the authenticationType must match the one 
    // defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    // Add custom user claims here
    return userIdentity;
}
```

**N.B.:** I have added properties to `ApplicationUser` which do not conflict with `IdentyUser`.

Comment: What error does the scaffolding throw and where? The method you posted shows that it is returning a `ClaimsIdentity`

Comment: UserManager<ApplicationUser> does not contain a definition for CreateIdentityAsync or DefaultAuthenticationTypes

Comment: To reproduce: VS2015 create a new ASP.NET web project with the MVC 6 template. Under Models in ApplicationUser.cs, add references to System.Security.Claims and Micosoft.AspNet.Identity and insert the code above into the ApplicationUser class. See the errors described in the comment above.

Comment: What you are describing will work in mvc 5 not mvc 6/core. checking now to see how it has changed in the new version

Comment: Please use the proper tags in future! When your quesiton is related to ASP.NET Core use "asp.net-core" tag ! NOT "asp.net" and "core", both are completely unrelated to your question. Please read the tag descriptions before adding them

Answer (score 16, accepted):

UserManager has changed in the MVC6 version. You will need to modify your code...

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager) {
    var authenticationType = "Put authentication type Here";
    var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(await manager.GetClaimsAsync(this), authenticationType);

    // Add custom user claims here
    return userIdentity;
}
```

Comment: AuthenticationType: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.authenticationtypes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I was learning how to add DAL/DTO classes to a new project based on ASPNETCORE from the public demo project Altostratus and noticed they have two of these async methods, one takes only `UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager` and the other takes `UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType` are they both needed? As I see in yours you just hard code the type message.

Comment: That depends on your needs. If there is no need for multiple types and it is unlikely to change then no. Otherwise do what works for your code.

Comment: If I have a MS SQL database that has user authentication setup already, do I put anything there or shouldn't it just be generic from the project template on aspnetcore EF? Tables being aspnetroles, aspnetuserclaims, aspnetuserlogins, aspnetroles, and aspnetusers.

Comment: Then use the default templates provided when you created the project. There are examples already available for when using multiple authentication providers.

Comment: This answer was based on the original question asked. If the default template using another format go with that.

Answer (score 2):

**.net core**

the answer has changed, per [here](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/security/asp.net-core-and-claim-based-security.html) and [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/add-extra-user-claims-in-asp-net-core-web-applications-1f28c98c9ec6), both authors state the use `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>` which is the default implementation for core 2.2. The first article says that the method you are looking for has moved. However, as stated you must register your implementation of `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` in services like so and a sample class implementation is below. Please take that we have to register `MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory` so our service collection knows where to find it. Which means in the constructor of `SignInManager<ApplicationUser>` it is also referring to `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>` but service will resolve it:

```
services
.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()              
.AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>() // <======== HERE

services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

And here is is the class below:

```
public class MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, 
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ContactName", "John Smith"));
        return identity;
    }
}
```